# Is it good to copy gemset from development server to production for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to Ruby on Rails , I have done development and now my app will go to production so I need some advice to update code on production server.
I have Created gemset on development server so , I am thinking that I will just copy the development Ruby gemset folder and paste it on Production so is it Good Idea or bad??

I never deploy code from development to production, so could any body
tell so Guide , I have follow some links but did not get any better solution. so Please guide me .

Any help highly appreciated Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Generally you would somehow deploy your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to production (ftp, rsync, version control, tools like capistrano etc.) and then run `bundle install` so that the correct gems are installed for your production environment.

Comment: @martincarlin87 Thanks . its really helpful for me..:)